# Pick number of files instead of percentage

Tags: python

I have modified the following code for my needs.

It randomly moves files from one directory to another.

Currently it is copying a percentage of files from one folder to another. What do I need to change to copy 3 files rather than a percentage?

Is this the bit I need to change?

```
"*.02)):"
```

My code:

```
import os, shutil
from random import choice

rootdir = '/Autoupload'
output_dir = '/Public'
for subdir, dir, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    if files:
        for x in range(int(len(files) *.02)):
            to_copy = choice(files)
            shutil.move(os.path.join(subdir, to_copy), os.path.join(output_dir, to_copy))
            files.remove(to_copy)
```

Comment: `int(len(files) *.02)` is the expression that determines what absolute number 2% of the files is. You can replace that entire thing with `3` to just copy 3 files.

Comment: Thank you so much Blorgbeard - that worked a treat! Much appreciated! My first question here and responded so quickly

Answer (score 2):

Using `random.sample` can do the trick for you:

```
import os, shutil
from random import sample

rootdir = '/Autoupload'
output_dir = '/Public'
for subdir, dir, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for to_copy in sample(files, min(len(files), 3)): # <- at most 3 files from each dear
        shutil.move(os.path.join(subdir, to_copy), os.path.join(output_dir, to_copy))
```

Comment: This is a better approach, since the logic is simplified and because it will avoid choosing the same file multiple times.